# ng-repeat-start with 3 different TR

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you want to repeat this structure with 1 TR/1 TD and 1 TR/2 TDs

```
          <tr>
            <td>Nitish</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>Male</td>
          </tr>
```

you can do this as taken from http://www.nitishkumarsingh.com/blog/advantage-of-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-repeating-over-multiple-elements/

```
   <table>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="l in list">
       <td>{{l.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat-end>
       <td>{{l.age}}</td>
       <td>{{l.gender}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

But what about adding one more TR with one more TD so 3 TDs after 1 and 2 TDs ?

```
          <tr>
            <td>Nitish</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>Male</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>767 Fifth Avenue</td>
            <td>New York, NY 10153</td>
            <td>(212) 336-1440</td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `ng-repeat-end` at last `tr`, so that intermediate template between `ng-repeat-start` & `ng-repeat-end` will get repeated.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="l in list">
       <td>{{l.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>{{l.age}}</td>
       <td>{{l.gender}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>{{l.addressLine1}}</td>
        <td>{{l.addressLine2}}</td>
        <td>{{l.phoneNumber}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```